# After upgrade from Vista to Win7, internet PPOE connection is unstable, keeps cutting out

Tags: windows-7, networking, pppoe, nvidia-nforce

I had a 64-bit Vista Ultimate desktop, and did an in-place upgrade to Win7 Ultimate. Hardware is a P5N32E-SLI motherboard, Q6600, 8GB RAM, 460GTX SLI. It is directly connected by ethernet to an FTTH modem.

I followed all of the compatibility guide suggestions to remove drivers, uninstall certain applications, etc. All nVidia video and chipset drivers were removed prior to installation.
No obvious issues occurred during the setup.

The existing PPOE connection was kept, retaining all of the account information.

Current symptoms are:

- PPPOE connects properly when dialed
- Internet works properly after connection
- Within 10 seconds to 5 minutes after connecting, the connection conks out
- No IP addresses can be reached by ping
- No web sites can be accessed
- No DNS lookups can be made
- PPPOE cannot reconnect

However, there is a workaround to reconnect:

- Reboot

Or,

- Open network adapter settings and disable the ethernet port
- Physically remove the ethernet cable
- Re-enable the ethernet port
- Re-connect the ethernet cable
- Re-connect to PPPOE

The internet then again works properly for up to 5 minutes before I have to do it again.
If I leave the cable physically connected, or reconnect it prior to enabling the ethernet port, PPPOE will still be unable to connect.

What I have tried already:

- Installed latest nVidia ethernet drivers
- Un-installed nVidia ethernet drivers and let Win7 install its own
- Installed older nVidia ethernet drivers
- Disabled IP offload
- Delete the PPPOE configuration and re-create the connection

None of these have had any effect. The computer is now useless for Internet access.

Another Windows 7 machine I have, using a G31 Intel chipset, works properly using the same FTTH modem and PPPOE account.

One difference between these machines is that in the Networking control panel, the working machine shows only the PPPOE connection, but the non-working machine always shows an additional network. This second network was not showing up when the system was still using Vista. However, IPCONFIG shows only the single PPPOE IP address and routes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked from the modem's end if its kicking the machine off for some reason?

Comment: @soandos Thanks for the idea. The modem provides no management interface, but I checked the the activity and connection lamps on the front. They indicate that the PPPOE connection is still active, even while the computer is unable to access the internet. My other Win7 computer is never kicked.

Comment: Is the modem negotiating PPPOE? or is a router doing past the modem?

Comment: As far as I know, the Windows machine is negotiating the PPPOE? There is no router. One ethernet cable between computer and FTTE modem, and then fiber to the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled all drivers including hidden and non_present_devices, reboot, re-install, reboot, and all clear.